# How to extract segment of LineString depends on given first and last Point

Tags: geometry, java, linestring

I am finding the Sub Segment on line String

I am having the First and Last point from Longer Line String, trying to extract the sub Line string from longer Line String, where new line string contains all points in between give first and last point

Looking for solution using java language

[image]

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: we use locationtech jts library